# Azure Storage SDK for .NET gives error when compiled with .Net Native in UWP app

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, .net-native

I have a UWP app in Windows Store and I believe that windows store compiles app using .Net Native tool chain before delivering it to users device.

My Code inserts/updates/deletes an object from storage table and it gets following error.

```
System.NotSupportedException: NotSupported_UnreadableStream. 
For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=623485

at System.IO.Stream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)

at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.NonCloseableStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Here is the code:

Delete Operation:

```
await AzureStorageTable.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.Delete(myObject));
```

Insert/Update Operation:

```
await DeletesStorageTable.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(myObject));
```

Thanks for advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple code. It worked fine on my UWP environment. The sample code as following:

```
        //Get Entity and set IEntity
TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<CustomerEntity>("Harp", "Walter");
            var retrieveResult = await table.ExecuteAsync(retrieveOperation);
            ITableEntity ite = (CustomerEntity)retrieveResult.Result;

//Delete Entity
        TableOperation deleteOperation = TableOperation.Delete(ite);
        await table.ExecuteAsync(deleteOperation);
```

According to your description, I think you should pay attention to two points:

1. Please make sure your table has the object which you want to delete.
2. Please make sure 'myObject' has the Tag property . Because the delete and update function needs this property.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Will, The Table operations are not working only when compiled with .Net Native tool chain in Release mode.